# Monstrous Mount - Animal or Magical Beast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I am playing a Goblin Hunter. When I reach 5th level, I am considering taking the [Monstrous Mount](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-mount/) feat to gain a Worg as my animal companion. The feat says that I follow all rules for an animal companion, except where it states that it is different. I assume this means that unlike normal Worgs (which are magical beasts), a worg gained through this feat would be an Animal.

I am confused by this because the [Animal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals) type says that no creature with an Intelligence score over 2 can be an animal. Is this a case where the specific rule trumps the general rule? Or would the Worg companion be a Magical Beast? If it is a Magical Beast, is that the only feature it retains from its monstrous stat block? For instance, most Worgs have racial modifiers to Perception, Stealth, and Survival. Would my Animal Companion Worg be absent those (basically a special worg that answers the hunter's call to become an animal companion, so it is not like others of its kind)?

There are other features of Magical Beast that could be problematic if it retained them, such as a Good BAB progression and a d10 HD instead of d8.

Comment: FWIW, Animal Companions can have 3 or more intelligence (see [Feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/animal-companions/#Feats)). It may or may not be useful to reference [Awaken](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The feat says that I follow all rules for an animal companion, except where it states that it is different. I assume this means that unlike normal Worgs (which are magical beasts), a worg gained through this feat would be an Animal.

It’s not super-clear, but I would assume the opposite: for one thing, the reason why your animal companion is an Animal is because it says to pick from a list that has only Animals on it, but Monstrous Mount says to pick from a different list, and there are Magical Beasts on it. For another thing, *this question*. If we assume the worg becomes an Animal during this process, *we need to know what that means*, because that’s not a typical transformation we expect from the system. So the very fact that Monstrous Mount doesn’t answer that question strongly suggests to me that we aren’t supposed to be doing that at all.

Also, it says you get a worg. A worg is a magical beast. If it’s not a magical beast, it’s not a worg.